# What is someone who answers a question called?

Tags: word-request

I wanted to use a short term to indicate the person that answers a question, for example you, who are probably going to help me with this problem; but the only thing that came to my mind is to say:

> "the person who answered to that question".

Does it exist such a term?

Comment: [Synonyms for "replier"](http://www.powerthesaurus.org/replier)

Comment: You're welcome! **Answerer** seems a good fit. (0:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *answerer* answers a question.

A *defendant* (or their lawyer) tries to defend themselves against a criminal charge in court.

A *respondent* (or their lawyer) responds to a motion in court.

As CopperKettle suggests, a *replier* replies to a statement or question.

A *torture victim* is someone who has been "put to the question" by the inquisition.

A *witness* is someone who testifies in court.  They may be subject to examination and cross-examination by the lawyers, and answer the lawyers' questions.

An *invitee* RSVPs.  (*Répondez s'il vous plaît* is French for "[Respond if it pleases you.](http://rsvpmeaning.com/)")

An *interviewee* answers a series of questions.  Policemen ask questions of *subjects*, *suspects*, *witnesses*, and *persons of interest*.  Employers interview *job applicants*.  Journalists also conduct interviews.  Talk show hosts interview *guests* and *callers*.